# Word for someone between technologically illiterate and literate

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I know that you call someone who is familiar with technology "technologically literate" 
and someone who isn't "technologically illiterate"

I am looking for a word for those who are in between those two.

Comment: **Layman** might work. _Technology appeals to the professional and layman alike._

Comment: literate is like pregnant. You are or you are not.

Comment: @Oldcat so if you can switch on a computer, use Google and write emails does that make you as literate as compared to one that can modify, lets say, the computer's registry or make a hack?

Comment: I'm not in charge of the definition of computer literate. However, I am not aware of any set of ranks and promotions defining levels of literacy. Once you are considered literate, you are literate whether you read comic books or absorb the most erudite scholarly works.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *computer semi-literate* might fit, which Urban Dictionary defines as

> A recovering Luddite, new to computers with a low skill level.
>   1) I ain't no computer semi-literate...I found the urban dictionary, didn't I?

Google books offers *semi-literate* as well:

> Whereas computer hobbyists are generally computer-literate, [many of
>   the newest generation of personal computer owners are only what might
>   be described as semi-literate](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=computer%20semi-literate&tbm=bks). The personal computer market still
>   represents a very obvious target  ...

Answer (score 0):

- Technologically informed.
- Technologically well-informed.
- Technological novice.
- Technological amateur - someone who loves and is familiar with technology but not good at it.
- Dilettante - someone who delights in it, dabbles in it, but not very good at it.

#### [novice](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/novice) (ˈnɒvɪs)

n

1. a. a person who is new to or inexperienced in a certain task, situation, etc; beginner; tyro
   b. (as modifier): novice driver.
2. (Ecclesiastical Terms) a probationer in a religious order
3. (General Sporting Terms) a sportsman, esp an oarsman, who has not won a recognized prize, performed to an established level, etc
4. (Horse Racing) a racehorse, esp a steeplechaser or hurdler, that has not won a specified number of races

[C14: via Old French from Latin novīcius, from novus new]

#### [amateur](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amateur) (ˈæmətə; -tʃə; -ˌtjʊə; ˌæməˈtɜː)

n

1. a person who engages in an activity, esp a sport, as a pastime rather than professionally or for gain
2. (General Sporting Terms) an athlete or sportsman
3. a person unskilled in or having only a superficial knowledge of a subject or activity
4. a person who is fond of or admires something
5. (modifier) consisting of or for amateurs: an amateur event.

adj

6. amateurish; not professional or expert: an amateur approach.

[C18: from French, from Latin amātor lover, from amāre to love]

#### [dilettante](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dilettante) (ˌdɪlɪˈtɑːntɪ)

n, pl -tantes or -tanti (-ˈtɑːntɪ)

1. a person whose interest in a subject is superficial rather than professional
2. (Art Terms) a person who loves the arts

adj

3. (Art Terms) of or characteristic of a dilettante

[C18: from Italian, from dilettare to delight, from Latin dēlectāre]
diletˈtantish ˌdiletˈtanteish adj ˌdiletˈtantism ˌdiletˈtanteism n

*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*

Answer (score 0):

I think 'technologically aware' would be a good half-way house. Someone who is technologically aware has heard of or perhaps used the technology concerned, so they're not completely ignorant of it, but they haven't had enough exposure to become totally comfortable with it.